# Simple join table assigning default values for each row (sql fiddle included)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure there is a very simple answer to this question, but I'm having a hard time finding it.

I have a table with settings belonging to users.

```
| user_id | setting  | value  |     
-------------------------------     
| 1       | paying?  | true   |     
| 2       | paying?  | false  |     
| 2       | demo?    | true   |     
| 2       | active?  | true   |
```

I also have a table with default settings, in case the setting doesn't exist for a particular user.

```
| setting  | value  |
---------------------
| paying?  | true   |
| demo?    | true   |
| active?  | false  |
| hidden?  | false  |
```

And what I need to do is return all settings for each user (using the default setting only if none is assigned to that user):

```
| user_id | category | value  |
-------------------------------
| 1       | paying?  | true   |
| 1       | demo?    | true   |
| 1       | active?  | false  |
| 1       | hidden?  | false  |
| 2       | paying?  | false  |
| 2       | demo?    | true   |
| 2       | active?  | true   |
| 2       | hidden?  | false  |
```

This join is not returning results for each user. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT u.user_id, COALESCE(u.category, g.category) as category, COALESCE(u.value, g.value) as value
FROM user_settings as u
FULL OUTER JOIN global_settings as g on u.category = g.category
ORDER BY u.user_id, u.category
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5936a/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross join distinct users with global_settings and left join the user_settings table on to this.

```
SELECT u.user_id, COALESCE(us.category, g.category) as category,
COALESCE(us.value, g.value) as value
FROM (select distinct user_id from user_settings) as u
cross join global_settings g
left join user_settings as us on us.category = g.category and us.user_id=u.user_id
order by 1,2
```